# How to get resource name from resource Id in azure cli

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-cli, nic

I need to get the network interface card name from the resource Id.

```
vmsList=$(az vm list --show-details --query '[?name!=`null`].[name]' -o tsv)

for vm in ${vmsList[@]}
do
   nics="$(az vm nic list --vm-name $vm --query "[].{id:id}" --output tsv)"
        
   for nic in ${nics[@]}
   do
       az vm nic show --vm-name $vm --nic $nic --query '{Name:name,Location:location}' -o json
   done
done
```

But it is giving us this error. 
**'/subscriptions/subscriptionName/resourceGroups/resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/networkInterfaceCardName' not found on VM 'VMName'** 
**ERROR: Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request'**

I know this error is because we just need to pass only network interface name to `az vm nic show` command. But I am stuck to get the resource name only from resource Id.

Comment: `az vm nic show` accept name or id as parameter. I imagine if you specify the id, you dont need to specify the vm name so `az vm nic show --nic $nic --query '{Name:name,Location:location}' -o json` should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- We got the below error when we tried to get NetworkInterface Name with Resource ID
  [image]

To get the NIC details of particular VM, use the below command

```cs
$virtualmachine = Get-AzVM -VMName "VMName"
$virtualmachine.NetworkProfile
$nic = $virtualmachine.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces
foreach($nics in $nic) {
   ($nics.Id -split '/')[-1]
}
```

[image]

To get the NIC details of all the VM's in a ResourceGroup ,use

```cs
$virtualmachine= Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "YourRGName"
$virtualmachine.NetworkProfile
$nic = $virtualmachine.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces
foreach($nics in $nic) {
   ($nics.Id -split '/')[-1]
}
```

[image]

***References taken from :***

[Azure VM NIC name using PowerShell](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-retrieve-the-azure-vm-nic-name-using-powershell)

[Network interface object for an Azure VM](https://www.itprotoday.com/iaaspaas/find-network-interface-object-azure-vm)